# Problem with schtasks command

Tags: batch-file, dos

This is the command i executed

```
schtasks /create /SC once /TN note /TR notepad /ST 17:00
WARNING: The Scheduled task "note" has been created, but may not run 
         because the account information could not be set.
```

What does that Warning mean.Why its not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft's documentation the warning means that its not allowing it to run under the user permissions.

> "This warning indicates that the remote domain could not authenticate
>   the account specified by the /u parameter. In this case, the remote
>   domain could not authenticate the user account because the local
>   computer is not a member of a domain that the remote computer domain
>   trusts. When this occurs, the task job appears in the list of
>   scheduled tasks, but the task is actually empty and it will not run."

I would try using the user and password params and see if it runs then.